# Dynamically hide JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have a .net c# webform using the JQueryUI tabs Example as per the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});  
</script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#divTab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#divTab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#divTab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#divTab4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="divTab1">
    Showing Tab 1
</div>
<div id="divTab2">
    Showing Tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="divTab3">
        Showing Tab 3
    </div>
    <div id="divTab4">
        Showing Tab 4
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve, is based on a condition in my code behind, is to hide specific tabs.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the JQuery hide() method:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

In code-behind, evaluate your conditions and register the hide() method invocation with ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Comment: Thanx for that,Before I register the script I added testing code as follows: $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
$("#divTab3").hide();
}); 
But nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you see if there is any message in javascript console in Chrome? Or in IE Developer tools? Also, see this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675357/jquery-ui-tabs-how-do-i-hide-a-tab-and-its-corresponding-div-when-i-close-it

Comment: It seems as if I needed to do something more along the lines of $("#tabs #divTab3").hide(); But now when I followed the RegisterStartUpScript is still put the script at the end of the doc even though its not supposed to. That might have something to do with me using update panels.

Comment: Eventually what I did as a solution was add an id tag to my list items: '<li id="liTab1"><a href="#divTab1">Tab 1</a></li>' and then add an asp:panel just inside the divContainter: 
<div id="divTab1"><asp:Panel id ="pnlTab1" runat="server">Showing Tab 1</asp:Panel></div>
Then in my code: liTab1.Visible = false;pnlTab1.Visible = false;