# Jquery DatePicker left-justifies first row of days

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am using JQuery1-11.1

I have a datepicker

```js
$(function() {
  $("#openDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: "-5Y",
    maxDate: "+0Y",
    constrainInput: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<TD>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" id="openDatePicker" NAME="OPEN_DATE" label="Open Date" class="Form80"></INPUT>
  <span id="createDateDay"></span>
</TD>
```

This works fine here when the snippet is run here via stackoverflow, but when I run in my application, the first row of the datepicker is left-aligned.

[image]
[image]

I tried removing all the jquery .css files
but got the same thing

[image]

Here is a picture with additional .css to highlight the cells

[image]

Any ideas for what might be causing this?

Comment: Just thinking about it.. Probably ALL the rows are left-aligned.. It is just that it is only noticeable with the first row,,,

Comment: You'll need to post code that reproduces the issue otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running in your environment? You're not adding any of your own CSS? Looks like there is a collision between some CSS and jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: Thanks #Zealander and #j08691: I appreciate that something is causing the problem, but I can't identify it and I can't yet narrow it down to something specific enough to post. I have removed all the CSS and all the styles (as far as I am aware) and I am still getting the issue - see the third picture

Comment: What do you see when you run this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwkptcvx/  I placed CSS to highlight the table borders. You should see empty cells on the left. Add my CSS to your app and post screenshot.

Comment: Thanks #Zealander. I added a screenshot. Indeed your jsFiddle does work correctly...

Comment: Just for completeness, now that I have identified the errant code and solved the problem, I added the errant code to a new jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bp69tt94/, in order to be able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have a style in one of your stylesheets that is causing this. Use Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to look at the styles that are being applied that row.

Answer (score 0):

The following was causing the error

```
<style>
.ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

When it was removed the problem went away.

The reason I had this code in the first place was a "hack" to hide one of my tabs as per [Jquery UI Tabs: How do i hide a tab and its corresponding div when i close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675357/jquery-ui-tabs-how-do-i-hide-a-tab-and-its-corresponding-div-when-i-close-it).

Thanks to everyone for their help. I am sorry I couldn't make the question more specific - had I been able to then I wouldn't have needed to ask the question...